# C# class with JSON file

Tags: c#, arrays, json, class

I'm new on C# and I don't know how can I work with json file. I want that my script search on json file on my site but I don't know how can I create class that work with that file.
This is my json file

```
{    
    "Name 1": [
        { 
            "license_on":true, 
            "webhook":"Discord Webhook",
            "serverName": "Server Name",
            "idDiscord": "Discord ID",
            "discordName": "Serse Dio Re",
            "ipAllowed": "IP allowed to use the script",
            "license": "License"
        }
    ],
    "Name 2": [
        { 
            "license_on":true, 
            "webhook":"Discord Webhook",
            "serverName": "Server Name",
            "idDiscord": "Discord ID",
            "discordName": "Serse Dio Re",
            "ipAllowed": "IP allowed to use the script",
            "license": "License"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want that when the resource is started, check from the site first if there is the name of the server that assigns it as a variable, if it exists it must print all the data only from that server, for example if there is Name 1 I only get the characteristics of the Name 1. This is my initial code in c #

```
public static void ReadSite()
{
    try
    {
        string site = "My Site where json file";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string data = wc.DownloadString(site);

        // some code
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.GetType()}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Please I need a class and an explanation of how to work with it. Thank you

Comment: Did you make this json file?

Comment: Yes, is wrong? 
I took a file as an example but I modified it

Comment: Not really wrong, but I don't think your `Name 1` and `Name 2` are actually arrays. Also, you might not want to put spaces in the names of objects. i.e. `Name 1` should probably be either `Name_1` or `Name1`. Spaces in names can cause issues.

Comment: Are the keys always Name 1 and Name 2?

Comment: I would suggest you look into JSON file structure. This is a good resource for that https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize) method (more info in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#how-to-read-json-into-net-objects-deserialize)). This will let you create C# objects from a Json file.

First you'll want to define a class, something like this:

```
public class JsonDataClass
    {
        public Name[] Name1 { get; set; }
        public Name[] Name2 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Name
    {
        public bool LicenseOn { get; set; }
        public string Webhook { get; set; }
        public string ServerName { get; set; }
        public string IdDiscord { get; set; }
        public string DiscordName { get; set; }
        public string IpAllowed { get; set; }
        public string License { get; set; }
    }
```

And create your object by passing in that data string:

```
var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDataClass>(data);
```

you can then use that object to analyse/print info.

Comment: Didn't work. 
Also, there won't always be two servers on my site, but each time I will add one. I would like every time I allow a person to start the resource, I just have to add it to the site without changing the resource.

Comment: @FabioPalombi what doesn't work?